# Have I got the wrong idea about opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

When I first saw this question:

[What factors should be considered when using urllib vs urllib2 vs requests vs http.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904106/what-factors-should-be-considered-when-using-urllib-vs-urllib2-vs-requests-vs-ht?noredirect=1#comment40545122_25904106)

I thought "uhoh, this is going to be an opinion based recommendation frenzy".

I decided not to flag it because technically it does ask for facts not opinions, so instead I posted a comment to this effect, intending to encourage folk to post factual responses.

Not long after a very senior poster posted a recommendation for their favourite library.   The answer they gave does *allude* to some of the architectural factors, possibly, that lead to this recommendation but is very opinionated rather than factual.

I don't know whether to downvote and comment to this effect, or to flag as "not an answer", or whether I have the wrong idea about this, and really Stack Overflow is accepting of this kind of thing?   I hesitated to find out by flagging and seeing if a moderator approves, or even commenting there in the question because I don't want to be flagging/hassling senior folk wrongly!

Clarification: my question is specifically about the dealing with *answer*, not the question.

To paraphrase:

"This answer, from a very senior person, appears to indicate that it's OK to answer a question that might draw opinions with ... opinions.   My understanding is that "something should be done about this" in a community moderation sense, and I am not clear what it is.   I don't want to do anything in the case of such a senior poster without being clear that it's the right thing.

Comment: Related blog post: [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: He's asking for facts, he got an opinion.  "Just not very convenient" isn't much of a fact.  That ultimately is the way these kind of questions always go wrong.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for the ref.   I think that it is a good discussion of whether the kind of question I pointed at is acceptable or not.   The thing I'm trying to understand is what should be done when the question is deemed acceptable, but the answer is opinion based - just the sort of answer we (supposedly, my understanding) didn't want.

Comment: You vote to close the question, despite the fact that an answer (accepted/upvoted or not) was posted.

Comment: IMHO the statement _"Just not very convenient"_ is not so much an opinion when supported with the GitHubGist link contained in the answer, demonstrating clearly the inconvenience of one solution vs the other. I think the answer is a good one.